# Code is supposed To extract data between * ie *989*= 0989*; Runs only once then doesn't please help

Tags: serial, uart

```
void loop() {
       char *stptr=&string[0]; 
       if(Serial.available() > 0)      
       {
          data = Serial.read();
          if(data=='*')
          {
            ib=1;jb=0;
            string[0]='0';
            //Serial.print("GOT INTO IF");  
            while(string[ib-1]!='*')
            {
              //Serial.print("Got into reading while");
              //Serial.print(string[i]);
              if(Serial.available() > 0)
              {
                if(string[ib]!='*')
                {
                  string[ib]=Serial.read();
                  ib++;
                }
              }
            }
         }
      }
}
```

Comment: Please put your code in a code block so it is readable.

Comment: Do you seriously need those commented lines?

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of code, not just snippets.  State a question and a context clearly in the body of the post, rather than just vaguely hinting at it as in the title.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
void loop()
{
    char *stptr = string; 
    if (Serial.available()) {
        data = Serial.read();
        if (data == '*') {   // Check for starting *
            *stptr++ = '0';  // Copy '0' to string

            // Loop until: no data in port, or second * received
            while (Serial.available() && '*' != (data = Serial.read())) {
                // Copy to string
                *stptr++ = data;
            }
            // Terminate string
            *stptr = '\0';
        }
    }
}
```